# DataFrame error when replacing nan

Tags: python, pandas

Am having an issue with the fillna() function on a dataframe. When I attempt to fill in all nan, I get the following error message:

```
File "/Users/ruby/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2197, in fillna
    raise ValueError('must specify a fill method or value')
ValueError: must specify a fill method or value
```

As far as I am aware, by not specifying a method or value, the default should be to fill them with `None`

You can find the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: The code is asserting that if `Value` is `None` then the `method` cannot also be `None`, what are you expecting in this case? In effect are you expecting no change or that `NaN` is replaced with `None` which doesn't make sense for numerical dtypes

Comment: The default value of `None` in this case does not mean it will fill with None, but that you have to specify something (so actually, that `value` has no default value, but always has to be specified)

Comment: So lets say I do:
    `pages.fillna(value=None,inplace=True)` then I have specified the value but I still obtain the error shown below. In terms of outcome, I want to replace all `nan`with `None`to then pass it on into JSON

Comment: No that is no different from not passing any params, as I stated the code is asserting that if `Value` is `None` then `method` cannot be `None`, so you can either do `pages.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)`

Comment: If I read correctly, @redrubia needs to replace all instances of `NaN` in the dataframe with `None`.  This is actually non-trivial given the implementation of `.fillna`, which uses the `None` value of `value` or `method` as a sentinel to determine which option the user wants to use.

Comment: The documentation says you can use as `value` "a dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each ... column", so perhaps creating a dictionary mapping all columns of the dataframe to `None` and supplying it via `.fillna(value=none_dict`) might work.

Comment: Note that replacing with None does not make sense for numerical columns (None will be converted back to NaN automatically). For object columns you can use `.where` and `.isnull`